# Can't configure Springboot to use PostgresSql

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I had my Spring Service and i had to migrate from oracle db to postgres.
this is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.test.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>consoletest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>consoletest</name>
    <description>testtesttest</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <logback.version>1.2.3</logback.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <docker.image.prefix>testimage</docker.image.prefix>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId> 
            <scope>test</scope> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mobile</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring data JPA, default tomcat pool, exclude it -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- HikariCP connection pool -->
        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>2.6.0</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
                <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <repository>${docker.image.prefix}/${project.artifactId}</repository>
                    <buildArgs>
                        <JAR_FILE>target/${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAR_FILE>
                    </buildArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and this is my application.properties:

```
app.name=ehconsole
server.max-http-header-size=65536

jwt.header=Authorization
jwt.expires_in=300
jwt.mobile_expires_in=600
jwt.secret=queenvictoria

security.basic.enabled=false

spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/b2b
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=com
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgresPlusDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true


security.ignored=true
logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=ERROR
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=ERROR
```

But when I start it, in log I can't see that postgres is starting. It seems that starts just the h2 embedded DB, and when I launch the search query it's seems it looking for data in h2.
This is part of the log of my app:

```
:"SQL Error: 90079, SQLState: 90079","logger_name":"org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-4","level":"WARN","level_value":30000,"requestId":"f5ed8571-c8ee-46ba-a420-0abdd862c0db"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-06-19T11:35:00.691+02:00","@version":1,"message":"Schema \"COM\" not found; SQL statement:\nselect request0_.id as id1_13_, request0_.area as area2_13_, request0_.case_id as case_id3_13_, request0_.cfg_id as cfg_id4_13_, request0_.direction as directio5_13_, request0_.document_id as document6_13_, request0_.name as name7_13_, request0_.parent_id as parent_i8_13_, request0_.queue_prefix as queue_pr9_13_, request0_.release as release10_13_, request0_.root_id as root_id11_13_, request0_.status as status12_13_, request0_.substatus as substat13_13_, request0_.system as system14_13_, request0_.ts_created as ts_crea15_13_, request0_.ts_end as ts_end16_13_ from com.request request0_ where request0_.id=? [90079-195]","logger_name":"org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-4","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"requestId":"f5ed8571-c8ee-46ba-a420-0abdd862c0db"}
{"@timestamp":"2022-06-19T11:35:00.719+02:00","@version":1,"message":"Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not prepare statement; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement] with root cause","logger_name":"org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[dispatcherServlet]","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-4","level":"ERROR","level_value":40000,"stack_trace":"org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Schema \"COM\" not found; SQL statement:\nselect request0_.id as id1_13_, request0_.area as area2_13_, request0_.case_id as case_id3_13_, request0_.cfg_id as cfg_id4_13_, request0_.direction as directio5_13_, request0_.document_id as document6_13_, request0_.name as name7_13_, request0_.parent_id as parent_i8_13_, request0_.queue_prefix as queue_pr9_13_, request0_.release as release10_13_, request0_.root_id as root_id11_13_, request0_.status as status12_13_, request0_.substatus as substat13_13_, request0_.system as system14_13_, request0_.ts_created as ts_crea15_13_, request0_.ts_end as ts_end16_13_ from com.request request0_ where request0_.id=? [90079-195]\r\n\tat org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)\r\n\tat org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)\r\n\tat org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)\r\n\tat org.h2.command.Parser.getSchema(Parser.java:682)\r\n\tat org.h2.command.Parser.getSchema(Parser.java:688)\r\n\tat org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1218)\r\n\tat org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1940)\r\n\tat org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2089)\r\n\tat org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1934)\r\n\tat org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1749)\r\n\tat org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1737)\r\n\tat org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:448)\r\n\tat org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:320)\r\n\tat org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:292)\r\n\tat org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:257)\r\n\tat org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:573)\r\n\tat org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:514)\r\n\tat org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1204)\r\n\tat org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)\r\n\tat org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1929)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1898)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1876)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:919)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:50)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:118)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:82)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:482)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)\r\n\tat com.sun.proxy.$Proxy108.findById(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat com.windtre.ehconsole.rest.UserController.getRequestByParameter(UserController.java:1048)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)\r\n","requestId":"f5ed8571-c8ee-46ba-a420-0abdd862c0db"}
```

Comment: Please post the exception as a normal Java stacktrace, not as this very hard to read JSON.

Answer (score 0):

change `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=com` to `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=public` or remove this line from properties file.

Comment: I readded HikariCP and now the error it seemes to be some configuration error like u propose.
"Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection"
But cancelling the schema doesn't work for me.